# How to reset AnonymousID in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On some reasons some users get `null` `AnonymousID` on my site. I want to reset them to new `Guids`, but how?

Trying to do this:

```
public void AnonymousIdentification_Creating(object sender, 
   AnonymousIdentificationEventArgs args)
{ 
    args.AnonymousID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

And this:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.IsAuthenticated && Request.AnonymousID == null)
   {
   System.Web.Security. 
       AnonymousIdentificationModule.ClearAnonymousIdentifier();
   }
}
```

`AnonymousID` reset to null, but not assing new. And no `AnonymousIdentification_Creating` invokes.

It there any way manually set or reset to new `AnonymousID`?

**UPDATED:** `<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />` also.

Answer (score 1):

By default Anonymous Identification is disabled in MVC. To enable this, you need to add the following tag in web.config under **configuration** => **system.web** tag:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
```

Comment: It is. Updated the post.

Comment: `AnonymousIdentification_Creating` is working for me on initial start, when browser has no coocky but not after `ClearAnonymousIdentifier`